# iOS SQLite3 multiple prepare statements

Tags: ios, sqlite

just an easy question.

I got an app that uses archaic code (I'm not the one who started the app :D)

Anyhow, it uses SQLite3....yeah....

So my SQlite3 is a bit rusty but when we have multiple query like so:

```
const char *query1 = "SELECT ... ";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query1, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    ...
}

const char *query2 = "UPDATE ... ";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query2, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    ...
}
```

Do I need to use:

```
sqlite3_reset(statement);
```

Before I call;

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query2, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
```

In the above example or does SQLite3 automatically call `sqlite3_reset()` function each time we call prepare statement?

Comment: Can I get a  reason for a down vote on my question ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you have called `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`, you *must* call `sqlite3_finalize()` to free the resources allocated for the statement.
This must be done before the `statement` variable is reused, or when you no longer need the statement.

`sqlite3_reset()` is needed only if you want to execute the *same* prepared statement another time.

Comment: Oh ok. I tried using reset and clear bindings and so far seems to work but maybe I change it use sqlite3_finalize(). I read on another Stackoverflow post that we shouldn't call finalize if we plan on reusing the same statement many times because it takes time to prepare a statement but I guess it does explicitly mention here to call finalize for every statement: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html

Comment: You are not reusing the statement object, you are just resuing a variable called `statement` that later points to a *different* statement object,

Comment: Rightio, but if I have a one-off query method where I poll a server every 5 seconds to get data and store it in the app's database, would I still call finalize in this case ? Would it be considered reusing the same statement object ?

Comment: It just depends on whether you are reusing that statement object.

Comment: you can't re-use a finalized statement (https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) as "It is a grievous error for the application to try to use a prepared statement after it has been finalized."

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you want to use `sqlite3_prepare_v2` statement, then `sqlite3_reset(statement)` statement is compulsory, otherwise there are chances to throw exception.

[Here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html), you can get more idea about importance for `sqlite3_reset(statement)`.

Enjoy Coding !!